# Order of operations in summarise

Tags: r, tidyverse, magrittr

What is happening in the first line of code and why does the result differ from the two next results?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

data.frame(A=c(2,2),B=c(1,1)) %>%
   summarise(A = sum(A),B = sum(B), D=sum(A)-sum(B))
```

yields D=0

```
data.frame(A=c(2,2),B=c(1,1)) %>%
   summarise(A = sum(A),B = sum(B), D=sum(A-B) )
```

yields in D=2

```
data.frame(A=c(2,2),B=c(1,1)) %>% 
  summarise(sum_A = sum(A),sum_B = sum(B), D=sum(A)-sum(B))
```

yields in D=2.

I can't seem to come up with an explanation to how the D=0 can be a result of such an operation. How can `D=0` be a sensible result?

Comment: Interesting (+1) also take a look at `data.frame(A=c(2,2),B=c(1,1)) %>% summarise(A = sum(A), B = sum(B), D=sum(A), E = sum(B))`

Comment: `mutate` seems to work fine. `data.frame(A=c(2,2),B=c(1,1)) %>% mutate(A = sum(A), B = sum(B), D=sum(A))`

Comment: From the definition of `summarise`, *summarise() is typically used on grouped data created by group_by(). The output will have one row for each group.* So maybe it happens because the data frame is not grouped? Whereas `mutate` which does not need groups works as expected

Comment: @Sotos, it should normally work just fine with ungrouped data, too. It looks like a bug to me

Comment: From `?summarise` - "*# A summary applied to ungrouped tbl returns a single row*" - it should work as documented behaviour. The issue also persists using a `tibble` instead of a `data.frame`

Comment: @docendodiscimus Definitely. I m not saying It should work like that.

Comment: The smallest example I can do that breaks it - `df %>% summarise(A=sum(A),B=sum(A))`

Comment: Looks like a bug. Caused by applying a function to a (single) variable already updated within `summarise`. Interestingly seems to work when you combine variables within a function (?) : `data.frame(A=c(2,2),B=c(1,1)) %>%
  summarise(A = sum(A),
            B = sum(B), 
            C = A,
            D = sum(A),
            E = mean(A),
            G = sum(A-B),
            H = mean(A-B))`

Comment: This is a bug, I have filed an issue at https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3233

Comment: Thought so too. Thanks for the quick replies.

Comment: I recommend using your last approach of renaming things. Another option is to use summarise (to compute sum of A and B) and then mutate (to compute the difference)

Comment: The order is also important... summarise(D=sum(A)-sum(B),A = sum(A),B = sum(B)) yields 2 4 2

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug, see https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3233. It is fixed in 0.7.4.9001.